# Know if MKMapView is showing map region or yellow grid in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, mkmapview

Is there are any way to know when `MKMapView` is showing the yellow grid when the app does not have an internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can register for delegate notifications and implement `mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:` -- see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:

On a related note, you can also use the [Reachability framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to check if your app has an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to know when user changes zoomIn and mapView pass to show yellow grid. When user changes to zoomOut, mapView show normal region map.

Comment: Check out the rest of the delegate methods on that page I linked to.  There's probably lots of stuff you would find useful, including, in this case "mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:" tells you when a user zooms in and out.